# Embedding youtube video

Tags: html, performance, youtube-api, pagespeed

I embed youtube video in my website like this:

```
<iframe width="320" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/12345678"
    style="border: none" allowfullscreen id="myVideo"></iframe>
```

This iframe's href downloads a this  which is 2.7 KB

That  download these:

- 287 KB http://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/watch_as3-vf123456.swf
- 40.4 KB http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-vf123456.js
- 26.7 KB http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-webp-vf123456.css
- 0.5 KB http://i3.ytimg.com/crossdomain.xml

So even though the user didn't watch video yet, he downloads nearly 356 KB data. What would be a better way to show Youtube video in my website but load these data when user wants to watch video ?

Comment: As long as you don't overpopulate your page with iframes, I'd say 356 KB of data isn't really something to worry about.

Comment: Yes but this lowers page's mobile performance..

Comment: That's the price you pay for embedding YouTube videos. You could try using thumbnails that redirect to the actual video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the thumbnails and only load the player when the user clicks the thumbnail

You can see an example of how to do this using  AngularJS on the Topic Explorer example

App:

https://yt-topic-explorer.googlecode.com/git/dist/index.html

View:

https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/views/main.html

Code snippet:

```
<div class="player-container">
        <img ng-click="videoClicked($event.target, videoResult.id)" ng-src="{{videoResult.thumbnailUrl}}" class="thumbnail-image">
        <div class="title"><a ng-href="{{videoResult.href}}" target="_blank">{{videoResult.title}}</a></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

https://code.google.com/p/yt-topic-explorer/source/browse/app/scripts/controllers/main.js

Code snippet:

```
function playVideo(container, videoId) {
    var width = container.offsetWidth;
    var height = container.offsetHeight;

    new YT.Player(container, {
      videoId: videoId,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 2,
        modestbranding: 1,
        rel: 0,
        showInfo: 0
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented it.